# Same erasure but not the same type.

Tags: java, generics, casting, erasure

**How can it be the case that `ArrayList<Class<?>>` has the same erasure of `ArrayList<Object>` but cannot be cast to it?**

My code is currently switching between two eclipse errors.

```
GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel transport = 
                new GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel(StringConstants.TRANSPORT,
                    (ArrayList<Object>)TransportManager.getInstance().getTransportTypes());
```

which shows:

```
Cannot cast from ArrayList<Class<Transportable>> to ArrayList<Object>
```

If I remove the cast however and create a constructor:
`GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel(String, ArrayList<Class<Transportable>>)`

I get the eclipse error that:

```
Erasure of method GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel(String, 
   ArrayList<Class<Transportable>>) is the same as another method in type 
   GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel
```

It then highlights the constructor (below) as the conflicting constructor.

```
GenericExclusiveSelectionPanel(String title, ArrayList<Object> arrayList)
```

Comment: Why would you expect that one type could be cast to another just because they have the same erasure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to understand why this happens if we first understand what *type erasure* means with respect to *Generics* in Java. Take a look at [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) from the Oracle documentation before proceeding.

Now that you know what type erasure means, lets look at what the the Oracle documentation has to say about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

It should be clear from the documentation that the primary goal of *Generics* was to provide tighter compile time checks. It would be quite a contradiction if the compiler did not enforce a check on *casting* with generics. For the sake of discussion, consider hypothetically that the following statements were allowed :

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();//1
strings.add("123");//2
List<Object> objects = strings;//3
objects.add(1);//4
```

If the compiler did not restrict the assignment at step 3, you would be able to add an `Integer` to a list of `String` objects. What good are *Generics* in the first place if the compiler doesn't complain about the assignment at step 3 which in turn allows us to go ahead with step 4?

Similarly, while `ArrayList<Class<Transportable>>` and `ArrayList<Object>` have the same erasure, the compiler is right in complaining about their assignment as explained above. In conclusion, restricting these casts with *Generics* is as important as restricting constructors/methods with the same erasure.